# Distance Thresholds - pgRouting

Tags: pgrouting, routing

I have been working with a set of data which mimics a shortest distance 'many to many' network analysis between COA population weighted centroids and education points in Bristol. My population centroids have been snapped to the road network, and I have tried various distance threshold within this section of code

```
-- ###
UPDATE bristol_coa11_centroids SET id = br.id
FROM bristol_roads_vertices_pgr br
WHERE ST_DWithin(bristol_coa11_centroids.geom, br.geom, 0.001);
-- ###
SELECT *
INTO test_route_v5
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT gid as id, source, target, length:: double precision AS cost
        FROM bristol_roads',
    ARRAY(SELECT id from bristol_coa11_centroids),
    ARRAY(SELECT id from bristol_education_v2), false) as be
    LEFT JOIN bristol_roads AS br ON be.edge = br.gid
    ORDER BY be.seq;

SELECT * FROM test_route_v5;
```

However, I have noticed that routes aren't being generated from all of the centroids (see image). Is there a way to get round this in Postgres or Arcmap first? I have measured distances from centroids and roads and determined different threshold against that but have seen no change. I need to expand the study size area so cannot afford to have a magnitude of points being missing. Thankyou!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check which ID is assigned to each point. Ideally, you would take a much larger distance, then keep the ID of the nearest neighbor.

That being said, it is likely not the issue here.

Even though you have instructed to use an `undirected` graph, you must still use set a `cost` **and** a `reverse_cost` (which can be the same).

```
SELECT gid as id, source, target, 
        length:: double precision AS cost, 
        length:: double precision AS reverse_cost
 FROM bristol_roads
```

See the examples from the [doc](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstra.html#additional-examples):

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM edge_table',
    2, 3,
    FALSE
);
 seq | path_seq | node | edge | cost | agg_cost
-----+----------+------+------+------+----------
   1 |        1 |    2 |    2 |    1 |        0
   2 |        2 |    3 |   -1 |    0 |        1
(2 rows)

SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table',
    2, 3,
    FALSE
);
 seq | path_seq | node | edge | cost | agg_cost
-----+----------+------+------+------+----------
   1 |        1 |    2 |    4 |    1 |        0
   2 |        2 |    5 |    8 |    1 |        1
   3 |        3 |    6 |    5 |    1 |        2
   4 |        4 |    3 |   -1 |    0 |        3
(4 rows)
```